# Is there any way to get log events from crashlytics / fabric into ELK or a SaaS metrics platform like datadog?

Tags: logging, mobile, crashlytics, datadog

If you use a stack like ELK or datadog for collecting server-side logs and events, how do you integrate mobile-side metrics? Is there any way to get these out of crashlytics directly, or does this log aggregation need to be implemented separately?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be a Crashalytics direct integration yet.

Datadog maintains mobile SDKs that can be included in mobile clients to produce metrics and logs to the platform.

For iOS Logs, see here: https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/log_collection/ios/

For Android Logs: https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/log_collection/android/

There's also a public Android SDK for Real User Monitoring, which can be read here: https://docs.datadoghq.com/real_user_monitoring/android/

And the announcement, with a link for the private beta for iOS signup here: https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/datadog-mobile-rum/